# PL/SQL Conditional statement using two tables within trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, join, plsql, triggers

I'm working on a simple trigger that updates the Quantity on Hand of a product when adding a new invoice line. 
I got that working fine; but I starting thinking that in a practical application it would be prudent to verify that the QOH is sufficient before allowing the update. I'm sure I could write a separate trigger for that, but I'd like to see if it's possible to join two tables for a conditional statement within a trigger.

This is as far as I've gotten; adding a SELECT statement anywhere in there causes all hell to break loose, so I'm a little stumped how I can declare the PRODUCT.P_QOH before calling the conditional.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_prod_QOH_on_line_add
    BEFORE INSERT ON LINE
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF :NEW.LINE_UNITS > PRODUCT.P_QOH THEN
            RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20202, 'Insufficient quantity on hand');
        ELSE
            UPDATE PRODUCT
                SET P_QOH = P+QOH - :NEW.LINE_UNITS;
                WHERE PRODUC.P_CODE = :NEW.P_CODE;
        END IF;
    END;
/
```

This isn't a major problem for me, as I said there is probably a different way; I'm just starting to learn this stuff and would like to see what's possible. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Frankly, I would *never* do a "for each row..." when I could just as easily write SQL to do the whole job.  Assuming P_QOH is a column in your PRODUCT table: `update product set PRODUC.P_QOH = PRODUC.P_QOH - LINE_UNITS where PRODUC.P_CODE = P_CODE and PRODUC.P_QOH >= LINE_UNITS`

Comment: Would that actually stop the INSERT, or only prevent the QOH from being updated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get into dangerous territory trying to enforce rules like this via triggers.  The solution you are asking for is:

```
create or replace trigger trg_prod_qoh_on_line_add
    before insert on line
    for each row
    declare
        v_qoh product.p_qoh%type;
    begin
        select p_qoh
        into   v_qoh
        from   product
        where  product.p_code = :new.p_code;

        if :new.line_units > v_qoh then
            raise_application_error(-20202, 'Insufficient quantity on hand');
        else
            update product
                set p_qoh = p_qoh - :new.line_units
                where product.p_code = :new.p_code;
        end if;
    end;
```

However this is **not** a safe solution in a system with more than one concurrent user.  Suppose product 'X' has p_qoh=10 and then 2 users do this:

```
user1> insert into line (p_code, line_units) values ('X', 7);

user2> insert into line (p_code, line_units) values ('X', 8);

user1> commit;

user2> commit;
```

Both sessions will see that 'X' has p_qoh = 10 so both will succeed and product.p_qoh will end up as -5.  All is corrupt!

The safe solution would be to create a check constraint on product:

```
alter table product add constraint prod_qoh_chk check (p_qoh >= 0);
```

Now your trigger can be simply:

```
create or replace trigger trg_prod_qoh_on_line_add
    before insert on line
    for each row
    begin
        update product
        set p_qoh = p+qoh - :new.line_units;
        where produc.p_code = :new.p_code;
    end;
```

This would raise a less friendly error message like:

```
ORA-02290: check constraint (MYSCHEMA.PROD_QOH_CHECK) violated
```

You can trap this in your trigger and give the message you want:

```
create or replace trigger trg_prod_qoh_on_line_add
    before insert on line
    for each row
    begin
        update product
        set p_qoh = p+qoh - :new.line_units;
        where produc.p_code = :new.p_code;
    exception
        when others then
            if sqlerrm like 'ORA-02291:%(MYSCHEMA.PROD_QOH_CHECK)%' then
                raise_application_error(-20202,'Insufficient quantity on hand');
            else
                raise;
            end if;
    end;
```

Now if we re-run the 2 user scenario above:

```
user1> insert into line (p_code, line_units) values ('X', 7);

user2> insert into line (p_code, line_units) values ('X', 8);

user1> commit;
```

At this point user2's insert fails with the error message:

```
ORA-20202: Insufficient quantity on hand
```

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate both the answer I asked for, as well as a better way to accomplish my goal.